Limit of a PolyLog does not work [bug]
This is an issue I am having with Mathematica version 13.1.0.0. I tried the following code, but it does not work as expected:
Limit[PolyLog[n, x + I a], a -> 0, Direction -> "FromAbove", Assumptions -> x > 1]
Limit[PolyLog[n, x - I a], a -> 0, Direction -> "FromAbove", Assumptions -> x > 1]
Limit[PolyLog[n, 2, x + I a], a -> 0, Direction -> "FromAbove", Assumptions -> x > 1]
Limit[PolyLog[n, 2, x - I a], a -> 0, Direction -> "FromAbove", Assumptions -> x > 1]


PolyLog[n, x]
PolyLog[n, x]
PolyLog[n, 2, x]
PolyLog[n, 2, x]


This is in contrast to how limit works with Log:
Limit[Log[x + I a], a -> 0, Direction -> "FromAbove", Assumptions -> x < 0]
Limit[Log[x - I a], a -> 0, Direction -> "FromAbove", Assumptions -> x < 0]


Log[-x] + I Pi
Log[-x] - I Pi


This is inconsistent with formulae on https://functions.wolfram.com/ZetaFunctionsandPolylogarithms/PolyLog/04/05/01/ and https://functions.wolfram.com/ZetaFunctionsandPolylogarithms/PolyLog3/04/05/01/, where the following limits are provided:
Limit[PolyLog[\[Nu], x + I \[Epsilon]], \[Epsilon] -> Plus[0]] == PolyLog[\[Nu], x] + (2 I Pi Log[x]^(\[Nu] - 1))/Gamma[\[Nu]] /; x > 1
Limit[PolyLog[n, 2, x + I \[Epsilon]], \[Epsilon] -> Plus[0]] == PolyLog[n, 2, x] - (2 Pi^2 Log[x]^n)/n! + 2 Pi I (PolyLog[n + 1, x] - Sum[(Log[x]^k Zeta[n - k + 1])/k!, {k, 0, n - 1}]) /; Element[n, Integers] && n > 0 && x > 1

Here is a more readable version of those limits:
$$
\lim_{\epsilon \to +0} Li_{\nu}(x+i\epsilon) = Li_{\nu}(x) + \frac{2 i \pi}{\Gamma(\nu)}\log^{\nu-1}(x) \quad \text{for} \; \; x > 1, \\
\lim_{\epsilon \to +0} S_{n,2}(x+i\epsilon) = S_{n,2}(x) - \frac{2\pi^2 \log^n(x)}{n!}+2i\pi \left(Li_{n+1}(x)-\sum^{n-1}_{k=0}\frac{\log^k(x)\zeta(1-k+n)}{k!} \right) \quad \text{for} \; n \in \mathbb{N}^+ \text{and} \; x > 1.
$$
I have a large expression which includes the Log function, the PolyLog function, as well as the Nielsen PolyLog function. The variable x appears in the arguments of these functions as x, 1-x, 1-1/x, 1+x, and 1+1/x. I need the limit of my expression as the variable x approaches the real axis from above and from below. I have tried implementing complicated replacement rules to mimic the Limit function, but I failed, and the results are too complicated to post here.
So, what is the best way to implement these limits with the limit function?

Maybe check out Normal@Series[PolyLog[n, x + I a], {a, 0, 0}, Assumptions -> a > 0 && x > 1] and Normal@Series[PolyLog[n, x - I a], {a, 0, 0}, Assumptions -> a > 0 && x > 1] and so forth.

@MichaelE2 That's a good idea! I may need to break up the problem for different regions of xon the real line, but that could work. Strange how Series seems to know these limits but Limit does not. This may be faster than using Limit anyways

I think it must be a bug in Limit[], since this shows that the correct series is used: Trace[  Limit[PolyLog[n, x + I a], a -> 0, Direction -> "FromAbove",    Assumptions -> x > 1],  _Series,  TraceInternal -> True,  TraceForward -> True]

@MichaelE2 Unfortunately this solution has problems for the function (x-I a)^r. Specifically Normal@Series[(x - I a)^r, {a, 0, 0}, Assumptions -> x < 0 && a > 0] and Limit[(x - I a)^r, a -> 0, Direction -> "FromAbove", Assumptions -> x < 0] are not compatible. For my specific case, I think I can work around this, but still frustrating there is no universal solution.

Hi, I'm not following your last comment. The two give the same limit and seem compatible with numeric tests. Ex.: lim1 = Normal@Series[(x - I a)^r, {a, 0, 0}, Assumptions -> x < 0 && a > 0]; lim2 = Limit[(x - I a)^r, a -> 0, Direction -> "FromAbove", Assumptions -> x < 0]; {lim1, lim2, (x - I a)^r} /. {x -> RandomReal[{-2, 0}], r -> RandomComplex[{-1 - I, 1 + I}], a -> 2.^-100}

https://functions.wolfram.com/ZetaFunctionsandPolylogarithms/PolyLog/04/05/01/ (A link in the post would have been helpful.) This last formula looks very fishy. I suspect it is intended to apply only when x==1. Otherwise the function for fixed nu is nowhere continuous in x.

@DanielLichtblau The formula is valid for x > 1. You should interpret $Li_\nu(x) = \lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow +0} Li_\nu(x-i \epsilon)$ because the PolyLog is defined here to be continuous from below. With this prescription that formula gives the discontinuity over the branch cut for x > 1.

@MichaelE2 I posted another question about my issue with the power function. If you get that lim1 and lim2 are the same from the code in your last comment, then it must be that my Mathematica version gives a different answer than yours.

Okay, I think I follow now. I'll look into it.

Bug report filed and under investigation
